# IOS - Swift - UINavigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe Error

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, swipe

I'm trying to hide navigation bar on swipe but i've got this error :

webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate:  -[UINavigationController setHidesBarsOnSwipe:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155a3a90

I'm using a webView and a navigationController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"http://www.myUrl.com")

    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!))

    webView.delegate = self;

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;        

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!) {        

    let url = webView.request?.URL.absoluteString

    if (url?.rangeOfString("/exportpdf") != nil ) {

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true; // ERROR

    }

    configureScrolling(webView)
}
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hidesBarsOnSwipe` is a property introduced in iOS8, but it is likely you are running the app in iOS7, which causes this error message.

Comment: Yes, i m in iOS 7. I 'm going to try in ios8. Thanks

Comment: What is alternate in iOS7 for implementing 'hidesBarsOnSwipe'